# Closed form expression for matrix sum

Tags: matrices, summation

We have the following sum for real numbers $a,b$

$$\sum_{n=0}^ka^nb^{k-n}=\frac{a^{k+1}-b^{k+1}}{a-b}$$

I am interested in a different sum, involving arbitrary matrices $A$ and $B$, and a third matrix $O$

$$\sum_{n=0}^kA^nOB^{k-n}$$

Is there an analogous formal closed form expression of this sum to the first sum presented possible?

Comment: If $A$, $B$, and $O$ commute, there might be hope.

Comment: Why not apply the same formula assuming the condition in the above comment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$
\def\m#1{\left[\begin{array}{l|l}#1\end{array}\right]}
$To avoid confusion, rename the third matrix to $C$ since $O$ looks too much like a zero.

Then take the $(k+1)^{st}$ power of a block triangular matrix
$$\eqalign{
M &= \m{A&C\\\hline0&B\\},\qquad
M^{k+1} &= \m{
A^{k+1}&\displaystyle\sum_{n=0}^k A^nCB^{k-n} \\\hline
0&B^{k+1} \\
} \\
}$$
Use an identity matrix $I$ the same size as $(A,B)$
and the Kronecker product $(\otimes)$ to define
$$\eqalign{
E_1 = \m{1\\0}\otimes I,\qquad E_2 = \m{0\\1}\otimes I \\
}$$
Then extract the $(1,2)$-partition, which contains the desired matrix sum
$$\eqalign{
E_1^T\,M^{k+1}\,E_2 \:=\: \sum_{n=0}^k A^nCB^{k-n} \\
}$$

Comment: This is impressive! Thanks.